# Visual Studio 2010 project builds fine using 32 bit, but get LNK2028 and LNK2019 errors when trying 64-bit. What could fix this?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010

I have a `Microsoft Visual 2010` project that runs fine in the `Win-32` compilation setting. I am running on Windows 10. I am trying to use the `x64` to build for `64-bit` but that is when I encounter the `LNK` errors (examples below):

```
error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A00015D) "extern "C" unsigned char __cdecl 
UcanDeinitCan(unsigned char)" (?UcanDeinitCan@@$$J0YAEE@Z) referenced in function 
"public: unsigned int __cdecl CAN::DeConfigDev(void)" (?DeConfigDev@CAN@@$$FQEAAIXZ)     
CAN.obj

error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "extern "C" unsigned char __cdecl 
UcanDeinitCan(unsigned char)" (?UcanDeinitCan@@$$J0YAEE@Z) referenced in function 
"public: unsigned int __cdecl CAN::DeConfigDev(void)" (?DeConfigDev@CAN@@$$FQEAAIXZ)     
CAN.obj

error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp___glewGenBuffers    Patient_GPU.obj
```

I've attempted to change the `/clr` function, as well as the calling convention (_cdecl ...) in an attempt to follow other solutions related to the LNK errors but neither has worked. Is there a different way to fix these errors, or get a better idea of what they actually mean? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you so much!

Comment: The list of libraries to be linked with is per build configuration. Looks like there are some libraries missing from the x64 configuration.  Compare the linker sections of the 2 (4 with release) configurations.  Also make sure you have 64-bit versions of the external libaries.

Comment: Also note that you must link with 64 bit libraries in x64 mode and 32 bit libraries in 32 bit mode. Meaning you would need different binaries for glew and the other dependencies between 32 and 64 bit.

Comment: Damn. Reminds me of this: ib.paths.ws/EjHqOp8O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably linking UCAN static library from somewhere. You need to make sure that in 64bit configuration, you link to 64bit `.lib` file.

First thing to check is Additional dependencies config and check what libraries are linked into the project.

Comment: Hello, thank you so much for the quick responses. Following your advice, I was able to find and link the different 64-bit .lib files. This reduced the errors from 22 errors, to 12 errors. Now they are all associated with a single file in the project. The errors are the same as printed above. I'm guessing it is because it includes a USBCAN32.h file which is for WIN32. However, I can't seem to find a USBCAN64.h file anywhere. Also, is there a USB64.dll file as well? Do you happen to know of these files or where they might be located? Thank you again!

Comment: @cloud77 Sorry, but I don't know the library you're using, so I can't advise more. I found this manual though, maybe there's some help in there? https://www.systec-electronic.com/fileadmin/Redakteur/Unternehmen/Support/Downloadbereich/Handbuecher/L-487e_02_05_USB-CANmodul.pdf

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I was able to get it to work by first finding the USBCAN64.lib and .dll files. From there, for some reason it kept trying to link to the USBCAN32.lib file (even though I had removed it from additional dependence and any calls in the code). I was able to work around it by removing the USBCAN32.lib file from the file directory, and just renaming the USCAN64.lib file to be USBCAN32.lib. It's a bit of a rudimentary fix but it seemed to do the trick so I'll take it. Thank you again so much for the help!